# custom input view keyboard functionality

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I wanted to ask a quick question just to make sure I am not missing anything simple before I  implement a more difficult method.  I need to create a custom keyboard for an iPhone application.  This I have already done by creating a view with the buttons, using a custom input view and it displays exactly like it should.  Now most of the buttons are standard numbers which need to update a UITextField in the screen that called the keyboard.  Does anyone know a simple way to do this?  I assume there has to be a built in function that the keyboard uses to send the information but I haven't been able to find any reference to it.  Otherwise I will have to go the more difficult route.  If anyone has a simple way to do this I would appreciate it.  I haven't worked with custom keyboards before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to do it the same way that Apple does it, as their keyboard is basically an input device, globally.

I recommend you just append the data in your button press multiplex method. Here's an example:

```
NSString *appendThisText = @"subtitle";
self.myTextView.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", self.myTextView.text, appendThisText];
```

Comment: That is pretty much what I was figuring I would need to do, but thought I would ask just in case I was missing something. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. I'd appreciate it if you could mark this as the answer :)

Comment: Absolutely.  Do you have any idea how to remove the rounded corners at the bottom corners of the custom view?  Is it possible to make it square?

Answer (score 0):

Custom keyboards are simpler than you realise.

`UITextField` conforms to the `UITextInput` protocol. That's a bit of a red-herring because this protocol provides all the really complex stuff like selecting text and so on. But `UITextInput` itself conforms to `UIKeyInput`. This is your friend.

The key `UIKeyInput` methods are:

```
- (void)insertText:(NSString *)text;
- (void)deleteBackward;
```

Your keyboard class should have a delegate (which points to the textfield that the keyboard is operating on) and you simply call these methods to insert and delete text.